# How to write a structure into a file in PHP?

Tags: php, data-structures

I have learned that to create a structure, I can create an array like so:

```
$MyStructure = array (
    'id' => '12345',
    'name'  => 'myName');
```

I also know, to write into a file, I can use:

```
file_put_contents($fileName, $myTextToSave, FILE_APPEND);
```

But, this function stores it in simple text format.
I want to know about functions such as in C-Language: `fwrite( &record, sizeof(struct myStructure), 1, fp );`

Is there any function in PHP which can store data in chunks of data-structure and then retrieve it in data structure format?

Comment: Use a database and every thing is simple

Comment: Database is useful when we have more number of fields with small amount of data in each field.
But, I want to use structures to store messages, comments given by a user.

Comment: A compromise might be to use `serialize`.

Comment: @Saurabh not true. In that case database is also useful, because it eliminates concurent writing problems. You can also use things like redis for even faster performance.

Comment: @ficuscr thats exactly what I just put into an answer! :-)

Comment: @Saurabh was your question answered? If not let us know how we can help. If so will you accept an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your structure to a file with file_put_contents as you have outlined in your post.

You can serialize and unserialize the arrays or objects into the file using the following documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

So it would look like this:

```
file_put_contents($fileName, serialize($MyStructure), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Thanks @trixtur !
May I get one more favor from you?
How to retrieve each of the structures separately?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could either write them into different files, or you could put a special delimiter between each, then do an explode on the file contents. Then loop through each of the resulting lines in the array and unserialize them.

Comment: I have been told I can be a little bit in-depth on my answers. If that is not understandable let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you must do it this way and cannot do without a database, then have a look at this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

But that is for storing data (binary). If you just want to store arrays in files, use serialize() or json_encode()